# Webbrowser control to run in latest IE version

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, http-headers, webbrowser-control

I have a problem where we need to run webbrowser control to run in system installed IE version.

Have already studied the pats recommendations for fixing it via reg key.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/

However cant use the FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION Registry Key as it will affect previous versions of my application.

Since i am not in control of the site which is being loaded, is it possible to add the compatibility meta tag from with in the code.

```
<meta http-equiv=”X-UA-Compatible” content=”IE=edge”>
```

Please recommend if any one has tried it before.

Comment: still no update :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , there are multiple choices available. 
But handling for all the sites is not suited as it will conflict with there individual implementation. 
Few options listed below : 
•   InsertAdjacentHTML
•   put_innerHTML
•   use IHTMLMetaElement reference for run time meta element creation. 
•   htmldoc’s Write() which overwrites the entire body.
•   On DocumentComplete event insert  by creating new element in HTML